# Spring Cloud Contract & Test Container

Tags: testcontainers, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, spring-cloud-contract

I am using Spring Cloud Contract, now I am making an integration test for event driven microservices.

Can i combine both Spring Cloud Contract (messaging) with Kafka container running on TestContainer? I want to use the StubTrigger of course but it should fetch the message also from my Kafka topic. Any suggestion? Does it even make sense? I think i am mixing the concepts.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. You can check out the examples with kafka and testcontainers here https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/main/consumer_kafka_middleware and here https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/main/producer_kafka_middleware

Comment: it seems like my message handler is not being invoked after the this.stubFinder.trigger("shouldPublishCustomerCreated_label"); I am using spring cloud stream kafka binder. Any help?

Comment: here is the detailed question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76285090/spring-cloud-stream-spring-cloud-contract-disabled-when-using-testscontainer @
Marcin Grzejszczak